# SSH "operation timed out" on ec2 instance

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2

I have performed the following steps:

1. Clicked on existing instance > Actions > Launch more like this
2. Kept all the settings the same aside from selecting a different instance type (same key name and security group)
3. I created an elastic IP and associated it with the new instance

Now when I run Terminal and do an `ssh -I MyLamp.pem root@1.23.45.67` I get the following error:

`connect to host 1.23.45.67 port 22: Operation timed out.`

I have checked the security group and can confirm it is not a permission issue there as I have 22 open (22  TCP 0.0.0.0/0   ✔), just like on my other instance which I can SSH into without a problem.

I have no idea what to try next to fix this so I can SSH in.

Answer (score 0):

[If you're using a non-default VPC](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/TroubleshootingInstancesConnecting.html#TroubleshootingInstancesConnectionTimeout), then you also

> need a route that sends all traffic destined outside the VPC (0.0.0.0/0) to the Internet gateway for the VPC.

[(own) answer pasted from [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/198916/63010)]